# matplotlib data accessible outside of xlim range

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot         as plt
import numpy                     as np            

time=np.arange(-100,100,01)
val =np.sin(time/10.)

time=-1.0*time

plt.figure()
plt.plot(time,val)
plt.xlim([70,-70])
plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

when I open the pdf in inkscape, I can select (with F2) the entire data, it's just invisible outside of the specified xlim interval:

[image]

The problem seems to be the line

```
time=-1.0*time
```

If I omit this line, everything works perfectly.. no idea why this is. I often need such transformations because I deal with paleo-climate data which are sometimes given in year B.C. and year A.D., respectively.

The problem I see with this behavior is that someone could in principle get the data outside the range which I want to show.

Has someone a clue how to solve this problem (except for an slice of the arrays before plotting)?

I use matplotlib 1.1.1rc2

Comment: Slicing the array before plotting is the way to go. Why do you not want that?

Comment: because it requires additional code and I would therefore prefer to use xlim

Comment: As an aside, any rasterized format (say `.png`) should not show this behaviour.

Comment: rasterization is not really an option, I like the advantages of vector graphic

Comment: This is a known bug  https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2423.

Comment: which now has a patch, could you possible test it?

Answer (score 1):

You can mask your array when plotting according to the limits you choose. Yes, this also requires changes to the code, but maybe not as extensive as you might fear. Here's an updated version of your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot         as plt
import numpy                     as np            

time=np.arange(-100,100,01)
val =np.sin(time/10.)

time=-1.0*time

plt.figure()

# store the x-limites in variables for easy multi-use
XMIN = -70.0
XMAX = 70.0

plt.plot(np.ma.masked_outside(time,XMIN,XMAX),val)
plt.xlim([XMIN,XMAX])

plt.savefig('test.pdf')
```

The key change is using [`np.ma.masked_outside`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ma.masked_outside.html) for your `x`-axis value (*note*: the order of `XMIN` and `XMAX` in the mask-command is not important).
That way, you don't have to change the array `time` if you wanted to use other parts of it later on.
When I checked with inkscape, no data outside of the plot was highlighted.

Comment: I was aware that the problem can be solved by altering the arrays, either thourh slicing or masking. I was looking for the solution using pyplot. Thanks for your answer anyway!