# Sloppy SVG generated by matplotlib resulting on poor clipping of datapoint drawing in figures

Tags: python, svg, matplotlib, render, clip

Figures that I create with `matplotlib` do not properly clip points to the figure axes when rendered, but instead draw additional points, even though such figures look fine in some viewers.

For example (following [an example from the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/users/transforms_tutorial.html#axes-coordinates)) using

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('SVG')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
x, y = 12*np.random.rand(2, 1000)
ax.set(xlim=[2,10])
ax.plot(x, y, 'go')  # plot some data in data coordinates

circ = patches.Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.25, transform=ax.transAxes,
                      facecolor='yellow', alpha=0.5)
ax.add_patch(circ)

plt.savefig()
```

I *seem*, when viewed for example in OS X Preview, to get

[image]

but when I view it in other editors, such as [iDraw](http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/) I get a mess (where, weirdly, there is a combination of correct clipping of edge points, failed clipping of points outside the axes, and clipping of the canvass at a point that does not correspond to either the axes or the range of data):

[image]

I'm not experienced with SVG, but those I've asked tell me that

> I looked at the SVG file and didn't like what I saw. Characters are
>   flattened, and definition sections are scattered throughout the file
>   instead of being at the top; some defs are inside graphics constructs.
>   There's a lot of cruft. It turns out the definition of the clip-path
>   is at the very end of the svg file -- after all the uses ...

How can I get `matplotlob` to generate SVG that does not have these issues? I know that I can edit the SVG, but I have no idea how, and doing so defeats the purpose and I hope that it is not necessary to add a "by hand" step to my workflow.

---

I'm interested in understanding what the cause of the sloppy SVG generated by `matplotlib` is: whether it's something that can be avoided by coding a bit differently (though not, clearly, by simply checking whether every data point is in range), or whether it's a bug in `matplotlib` (or perhaps whether it's just a problem with ambiguities in the SVG standard). The goal is getting `matplotlob` to generate SVG that is not buggy.

Comment: any reason you do not `savefig` as png originally?

Comment: Have you tried different backends? I once had problems with PDF output where switching the backend helped. Also it might be feasible to export in eps or pdf format and then use an external program to convert to sag.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: The question is how to generate SVG directly. The output needs to be SVG and adding other tools to the workflow is something I'd like to avoid (and shouldn't be necessary). Does `matplotlib` just generate bad SVG in general?

Comment: @behzad.nouri: The question is about generating SVG, not PNG.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius the question was that if it is going to be rendered to png at the end, any reason you do not savefig as png originally? do you understand it now or should i explain more?

Comment: @behzad.nouri: I'm interested in understanding what the cause of the sloppy SVG generated by `matplotlib` is. Whether it's something that can be avoided by coding a bit differently, or whether it's a bug in `matplotlib` (or perhaps whether it's just a problem with ambiguities in the SVG standard). PNG is not the goal, just (as in the question) an example of a place where the problem manifests. The goal is SVG that is not buggy.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius two people here have already suggested you to use different backend or figure format; so maybe you need to edit your question to clarify that you just want to understand svg in general and that png rendering is not really an issue you care about.

Comment: @behzad.nouri: Agreed. I've edited the question to make things clearer.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: Question updated for better focus.

Comment: @DavidZwicker: Note that using the "Agg" backend to generate PNG produces the same results; however, using "Agg" to generate EPS and then converting the EPS to SVG *seems* to work (*partly*: my fonts are ignored, which may be a separate question). If someone can confirm for me that the Agg-EPS to SVG process does indeed work for them to generate better SVG, then "try different backends" may indeed be an answer (which would be even better if it enlightened me a bit on why the "PNG" backend does such a bad job).

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to a know issue and also comes up in pdfs ([matplotlib data accessible outside of xlim range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19022601/matplotlib-data-accessible-outside-of-xlim-range))

See Issues [#2488](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/2488) and [#2423](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/2423) (the later which includes a proposed fix for pdf).  It is milestoned for 1.4.

Comment: That would be great. It does seem like a bug. I can work around it with exports and conversions, etc.; but is there some way to force points to crop at the axes from within `matplotlib` (or is it supposed to be doing that already)?

Comment: It _should_ be dropping non-visible points.  That it is not is the bug.